# Add another event source FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I try to add another event source on my FullCalendar. First, I get all events from manual function that I create own and I render all events using **renderEvent** function. But, I got error when I try to add another event source. So, I want to add holidays feature. I create another event source to get holidays date. That event was success to showed in my FullCalendar. But there is weird thing.
Example : If I have range of my holiday date, such as start : 2019/02/26 - end : 2019/02/28. The event content length doesn't 26 until 28, but start from 26 until 27.
[image]

What it's wrong? This is my code for to get all events.

```
// Get Agenda Data
function getEvents(datas) {
  $("input[name=unitAgenda]").attr("value", 
  $("select[name=unit]").val());
  var reUnit = datas.replace("- ","");
  $('.calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
  $('.calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'agendakerja/kalender/get_events',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { unit: reUnit },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data["events"], function (index, event) {
            $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
        });
    }
});
//passing unit name to function
global = reUnit;
}
```

And this is my code for get holidays date.

```
eventSources: [
   { url: 'agendakerja/kalender/get_holidays' }
]
```

Please help me!

Comment: assuming your events have only dates and not times in the `start` and `end` properties, then actually this is expected behaviour. Read the section on the "end" property in this documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object. In other words, if you made your `end` to be `2019/02/28` then this is treated as midnight on that date, and since the end date is _exclusive_, fullCalendar (as per the docs) interprets the event as ending _just before_ midnight. Therefore it will not appear to cross into the 28th at all.

Comment: In fact, in views (like "month") which only show whole days, it won't appear to cross into the next day unless the end time is greater than the time specified in the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold setting

Comment: Oh thankyou so much. It's very helpful. @ADyson